# Replacing threads with tasks

Tags: c#, .net

New to threading and tasks here :)

So, I wrote a simple threading program that creates a few threads and runs them asynchronously then waits for them to finish.

I then changed it to a Task. The code does exactly the same thing and the only change is I change a couple of statements.

So, two questions really:

1. In the below code, what is the difference?
2. I'm struggling to figure out async/await. How would I integrate it into the below, or given all examples seem to be one method calls another that are both async/await return is this a bad example of using Task to do background work?

Thanks.

```
    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    ThreadSample();
                    TaskSample();
                }

                private static void ThreadSample()
                {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    MyThreadTest[] myThreads = new MyThreadTest[4];
                    Thread[] threads = new Thread[4];

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        myThreads[i] = new MyThreadTest($"T{i}", r.Next(1, 500));
                        threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myThreads[i].ThreadSample));
                        threads[i].Start();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        threads[i].Join();
                    }

                    System.Console.WriteLine("Finished");
                    System.Console.ReadKey();
                }

                private static void TaskSample()
                {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    MyThreadTest[] myTasks = new MyThreadTest[4];
                    Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        myTasks[i] = new MyThreadTest($"T{i}", r.Next(1, 500));
                        tasks[i] = new Task(new Action(myTasks[i].ThreadSample));
                        tasks[i].Start();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        tasks[i].Wait();
                    }

                    System.Console.WriteLine("Finished");
                    System.Console.ReadKey();
                }

            }

            class MyThreadTest
            {
                private string name;
                private int interval;

                public MyThreadTest(string name, int interval)
                {
                    this.name = name;
                    this.interval = interval;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Thread created: {name},{interval}");
                }

                public void ThreadSample()
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(interval);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{name} At {i} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    }
                }

                public void TaskSample()
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(interval);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{name} At {i} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to use Tasks a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 4):

The Task Parallel Library (TPL) is an abstraction, and you shouldn't try to compare Tasks directly with threads. The `Task` object represents the abstract concept of an asynchronous task - a piece of code that should execute asynchronously and which will either complete, fault (throw an exception) or be canceled. The abstraction means you can write and use such tasks without worrying too much about exactly how they're executed asynchronously. There are lots of useful things like `ContinueWith()` you can use to compose, sequence and otherwise manage tasks.

Threads are a much lower level concrete system facility that can be used to run code asynchronously, but without all the niceties you get from the Task Parallel Library (TPL). If you want to sequence tasks or anything like that, you have to code it yourself.

In your example code, you're not actually directly creating any threads. Instead, the `Action`s you've written are being executed by the system thread pool. Of course, this can be changed. The TPL abstraction layer provides the `TaskScheduler` class which you can extend - if you have some special way of running code asynchronously, you can write a `TaskScheduler` to use TPL with it.

`async`/`await` is 100% compiler sugar. The compiler decomposes an `async` method into chunks, each of which becomes a `Task`, and those chunks execute sequentially with the help of a state machine, all generated by the compiler. One caution: by default, `await` captures the current `SynchronizationContext` and resumes on that context. So if you're doing this in WPF or Windows Forms, your continuation code after an `await` isn't actually running in a thread at all, it's running on the UI thread. You can disable this by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Really, `async`/`await` are primarily intended for asynchronous programming in UI environments where synchronization to a main thread is important.

Comment: Great thanks. As is the other answer. I'll mark this as the answer as it was the top item in the list when I got here. I'll now go away and figure more out.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. In the below code, what is the difference?

The difference is big. `Task` is a unit of work, which will use a thread(s) from *thread pool* allocated based on estimated amount of work to be computed. if there is another `Task`, and there are paused, but still alive threads, in the pool, instead of spinning of a new thread (which is very costy) it reuses already created one. Multiple tasks can end-up using the same thread eventually (non simultaneously obviously)

Task based parallelism in nutshell is: Tasks are jobs, ThreadPool provisions resource to complete those jobs. Consequence, more clever, elastic thread/resource utilization, especially in general purpose programs targeting variety of execution environments and resource availability, for example VMs on cloud.

> 2. I'm struggling to figure out async/await.

`await` implied dependency of one task from another. If in your case you don't have it, other than waiting all of them to complete, what are you doing is pretty much enough.
If you need, you can achieve that with `TPL` too via, for example, [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Very nice write-up, but one point of clarification. Tasks don't _necessarily_ run on the thread pool. One can create a task to run on a custom TaskScheduler. By far the thread pool is the most commonly used, but I think it's important that the TPL is not completely coupled with the thread pool.

Comment: Great thanks. As is the other answer. I've marked the other  as the answer as it was the top item in the list when I got here and both were about the same time.

Comment: @tigran, So we could not use tasks as a replacement for background threads? I mean if we have a logic which should be running as a service or any other long-running reason, we should still use threads.

Comment: @HamidMayeli: sure you can, Task, provided well designed scheduler, is an abstract concept describing unit of work, hence it might use available threads more efficiently, as for example, multiple task, might end up using the same thread, as scheduler might figure that they do not have overlapping concurrency, and that is a good thing, as spinning a new thread has its own cost. In short you can do whatever you want, it's just another tool in box.

Comment: @tigran, thanks for the quick response. Let me put it in an example. If I had a WebSite which needs to send emails as notification to the users. And I want to have a background task running for the lifetime of the process. It may be alive for months. From the design point of view, is it acceptable to make it a task instead of a thread?

Comment: @HamidMayeli: if you already know that the "task" assigned to it has app long lifetime, I would go with thread, as it is being still a unit of work, but it's unit of work that never ends, so there is *no* potential need to orchestrate it with any other temporary work to be done throughout the execution of application.